# Electron.js \app.asar\node_modules\{modulename}\bin\file.exe not found

Tags: vue.js, electron, handbrake, asar

I'm working on electron.js application with vue cli. I want to use handbrake-js which uses handbrakeCLI to encode files. handbrake.js is working great but after i spawn, it causes `HandbrakeCLINotFound: HandbrakeCLI application not found: C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\Electron.js Projects\video-compressor\dist_electron\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\handbrake-js\bin\HandbrakeCLI.exe.`

In my app.asar.unpacked folder, everything seems great. handbrake cli exists.

Answer (score 0):

The point is changing execution file folder "app.asar" to "app.asar.unpacked" in sourcecode of that node module. For more information, you can check: https://github.com/75lb/handbrake-js/issues/34